# meaning of "a priori"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading an article, but a sentence confuses me.

> On one side, novels and films are opposed as “words” and “images,” agreed to be irreducible, untranslatable, a priori entities by most postmodern as well as prior scholars.

Here, what does "a priori" mean? I know what is "A Priori and A Posteriori," but in this sentence the meaning that I know does not make sense!

Comment: You are justified in being confused. This use of *a priori* is not standard.

Answer (score 3):

Prof. Elliott employs *a priori* in its ordinary sense of something assumed or given **before** developing an argument, and thus not subject to qualification in the course of the argument.

She is exploring what she sees as a paradox: although most critics, from Lessing to Barthes and Foucault, assume ***a priori*** that novel and film (*aliter* "words" and "images") are utterly distinct entities which cannot be reduced or translated into each other, in *practice* the very same critics

> propound film’s integral formal, generic, stylistic, narrative, cultural, and historical connections to the novel. Somewhat perplexingly, the two sides of the paradox tend to coexist within single critical works: they do not, by and large, represent differing views of opposed critics.
>
> — [Kamilla Elliott, "Novels, Films, and the Word/Image Wars", in Stam and Raengo, eds., *A Companion to Literature and Film*, 2004](https://www.lit.auth.gr/sites/default/files/a_companion_to_literature_and_film_-wiley-blackwell_2004.pdf)

Comment: One can **assume** something *a priori*, but that does not make it meaningful to speak of *a priori* **entities**. One may assume *a priori* that novels and films are distinct entities, but that does not make it correct to say that they **are** *a priori* entities, and it is this use of *a priori* with *entities*, rather than, say, *assumptions*, that the OP is reacting to.

Comment: @jsw29 In my academic career I encountered *a priori* far more often as an attributive adjective than as an adverb or noun; and the first three dictionaries I consulted (Longman's, Oxford, MW) listed the adjectival as the first or only sense. *Film* and *novel* (as opposed to films and novels) are clearly "entities" which may be reasonably described as *a priori*.

Comment: True, *a priori* is very often used as an attributive adjective. The point of my comment, however, is that (whether as an adjective or as an adverb) it always qualifies something in the nature of believing, knowing, assuming, not things such as novels or films. Something is *a priori* if it does not require experience for its justification; that can be said of knowledge, but not of an entity (a thing).

Comment: @jsw In context (I've added a link) Prof. Elliott is not speaking of concrete individual entities but of the categorical entities "novels" and "films" -- the genres.

Answer (score -1):

//On one side, novels and films are opposed as “words” and “images,” agreed to be irreducible, untranslatable, a priori entities by most postmodern as well as prior scholars."//

Q: Here, what does “a priori” mean?  I know what “A Priori and A Posteriori” mean, but in this sentence, the meaning that I know does not make sense.

A: Although StoneyB provides so far the best background information to Dr.  Eliott's statement, it still doesn't answer the basic questions of the poster.

The author opens her statement with a prepositional phrase, “on one side,” which in a debate, lets the reader of her statement know there's also going to be another side to this.  Since StoneyB has already fully explained novels and films quite adequately, there's no reason to restate what he says again here.

What needs to be mentioned is that the author of this statement has taken a compound subject [novels and films], and on this one side of what is probably a long standing debate, she is going to discuss, but first, renames both as “a priori entities.”

The question to answer for the poster is why.  Why would the author of this statement take two simple or singular nouns, both novels and films, make both into a compound subject, then tell me, the reader that they are stating is already agreed on by postmodern as well as prior “scholars” [definition “Scholar” Merriam-Webster: (noun): 1. a person who attends school or studies under a teacher (PUPIL). 2. a. A person who has done advanced study in a certain field.  b. A learned person. 3. A holder of a scholarship.]

To answer the poster's question then as to why the author of the statement refers both novels and films as “a priori entities” needs to be explored.  To do that, a reader has to ask more questions.  Questions like, “What attribute about a book is “a priori?”  Both contain specific knowledge of some subject or theme vs. completely devoid of any?  Certainly then, novels would seem to be the opposite, and by themselves on a shelf or film in a movie theater, best classified as "a posteriori." Why? Because the film or novel is already published. It's already gone from a general script outline or story script into a completed novel or film. It exists only by inductive reasoning that a film director/producer or novel author/editor/publisher placed the film in a theater or in a bookstore. Many novels sit on a library shelf where some aren't read for decades, but I'm sure the author hoped it would have been read by everyone. Consequently with film, it's only "a posteriori" as to whether the general public get up and go see the film or not.

The poster caught on, this other side of the coin with "a priori vs. a posteriori." So, what other attribute then about novels and films is there that would cause the author of this statement to call them "a priori entities," and as she states, have most postmodern scholars and those prior scholars agree with her statement?

Well, who reads novels?  Who goes to films?   Does the sky read a novel, or chickens, or trees?  If I use deductive reasoning, the answer for most is probably no, no chickens have been observed reading novels.  If they don't, then who does?  Probably most people  deduce people read novels.  People go see films.   Then I have to ask, what kind of people read novels?  What kind of people watch films?  Is it the author of the book that writes it, then asks for 100,000 copies to be printed? Is it the author that then goes to 15,000 separate stores all over the country to buy all of his or her novels? Read each one again? The answer is probably no.  Isn't the author more on another side (the a posteriori side) of this debate?  Yes, the author starts out with a basic outline for a novel, then goes from the general to the specific in completing it, much as a film producer uses a general script to start off generally with a film, and gets specific in completing it. This is, of course, an attribute of both.  Most have to rule the author of the book or producer of the film out of this side of the debate, since both authors and film producers lay more heavily on "a posteriori, as they already experienced the plot and conclusion of the novel, or know the entire story board to ending of the film.  Still, film and novel publishers or people involved in their creation are not the most. The most that deal with novels or films is a  vastly larger group of people in the billions.

What's left then, as an attribute of both novels and films to be referred to as “a priori entities” is a general public of people. A population that may only have a general knowledge or idea or come to a novel or film with no previous knowledge other than with general knowledge of what they saw in an advertisement that compels them to read or view either. This is all they have, before they purchased a novel or went to a theater and purchased a ticket to go see the film.

Isn't also true, like Shakespeare with his plays, that film producers or directors, or novel authors, editors, and producers are people with only inductive knowledge of their finished work? A novel may not be liked by the general public; yet, inductive reason based on indicators, the public will like the novel was done beforehand, but it's not guaranteed. So, both create novels and films for a vast populace of people that don't have to know anything other than a general advertisement about what is in either a novel or film; but, even if the general public is invited to either read it or go see it, they my chose not to, and never have knowledge of what is in either. If people are this "a priori" attribute, haven't we observed in our lives this phenomenon firsthand? Haven't we ourselves actually paid money to buy a book or movie ticket, with only a general knowledge from an advertisement about what we are going to read or see?  Told we needed to purchase the novel in order to complete a college course and have it before we start the course?  If film and novel have this dynamic attribute of people as a priori,  most would agree with the author of her statement.

So yes, on one had, novels and film are specifically created for an "a priori" general people audience. Most scholars such as Shakespeare's "Hamlet" 1st Folio, 1623 [internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/Ham_F1] is one of those prior to postmodern scholars who agreed with the author's assessment.

Therefore, since most people reading novels or going to see a film are "a priori," the dynamic of people's interaction with novels and films going from the general to the specific as they open the novel and proceed through the pages to its' end, they started with a very general idea, but finish with very specific information, and they did this without having have any  previous knowledge about the content of either.  For most, it may not take that much now for a reader to agree with the author in calling both novels and films "a priori entities."

CONCLUSION: To arrive at this, a reader has to do a close read of the text in the statement. Look up key words in the dictionary. Examine grammar and syntax. The reader making his or her own notes and assessments on the author's statement, much like one chained to a seat facing a wall seeing images of words danced on a screen illuminated by artificial light (ref: "Plato and the Allegory of the Cave" https://web.stanford.edu/class/ihum40/cave.pdf    Since the statement starts off with a prepositional phrase, “on one side,” it's probably prudent that the reader use compare and contrast (ref: University of North Carolina "Comparing and Contrasting" https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/comparing-and-contrasting/) to extract at least the author's side of this debate. Even if author doesn't expound on the other side, asking questions or expending a little research and listing some things that might be on the other side of this debate help the reader adequately deal with bias. Both sides help a reader remain unbiased, which a reader logically clarify what the author is trying to tell them, even though the cave this is done in is quite dimly lit.

That's it.  I hope this answers your question. That “a priori” still means exactly what it means in the dictionary. This is only a fellow readers assessment of why the author applied "a priori entities" to both novels and films, and maybe only for me it made sense.

Answer (score -1):

*A priori* means "to begin with,"or, "the accepted premise." The author of the sentence seems to suggest that images and words are both irreducible in meaning both in the Post Modern era and in the era that came before postmodernism. (I am avoiding the use of "prior" in my answer since it further confuses the "a priori" in question in the original sentence, in the two words' similarity.) To confuse things even more, I am not sure the statement itself should be taken as a matter of fact. The statement itself seems debatable! My opinion, however, on that matter is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: The author is profound, and yes, the statement itself has been contested for centuries. Nicely done!